# Jpa, SpringData Concurrency issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, concurrency, spring-data, aop

I have two endpoints for editing same entity (Foo), one for property A, second for property B.

> /api/v2/foo/{foo_id}/a/{value}
>
> /api/v2/foo/{foo_id}/b/{value}

```
@Entity
Class Foo {

  // id, properties

  @OneToOne
  private Bar bar;
}
```

And nested class

```
@Entity
Class Bar {
  private String a;
  private String b;
}
```

This endpoints made concurrent action in the service of the entity Foo

```
@Service
public class FooService{
  @Autowired
  private FooRepository fooRepository;

  void updateA(ADto adto){
    Foo tmp = fooRepository.findById(adto.getId());
    doLogic...
    fooRepository.saveAndFlush(tmp);
  }

  void updateB(BDto bdto){
    Foo tmp = fooRepository.findById(bdto.getId());
    doLogic...
    fooRepository.saveAndFlush(tmp);
  }
}
```

These two call are concurrent and my data is corrupted.
Tried to put in Foo entity

```
@Version
private Integer version;
```

I get exception when trying to save second call.
My goal that i want to achieve is when i save the domain if saving fails from concurrency to refresh the latest version and to save changes.

Can anyone suggest to me some approach ???

Comment: "This is nothing Spring Data is causing. The means of control for that are in the JPA and database areas. I suggest you read up on optimistic locking with JPA as well as unique indexes in databases." -- Oliver Gierke

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using @DynamicUpdate if you want to update different fields.

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid having concurrent requests result in corrupted data is to use database transactions.

The posted code doesn’t show anything to indicate where your transaction boundaries are. Maybe the transactions are in your repositories? Maybe you turned on auto commit? In any event you need to implement transaction-handling in the service layer.

- Add @Transactional to the service class. Check that this is the spring annotation and not a javax one.
- Check the configuration for your JPA provider to make sure autocommit is off.
- Check that your version field maps to a database column.